# Extra Ampersand Getting set in request thereby fetting false response

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, ascii

Whenever I search for something that has an apostrophe " ' " like tai'an City in my application, the request is sent to the database team it goes as:  `tai&amp;amp;#x27;an city`. It is adding an extra Ampersand which is failing the request ( ASCII value of ' --> &amp;#x27; ). If the extra ampersand is removed manually e.g `tai&amp;#x27;an city`,the request is processed successfully.

If I manually set the request or try to replace &amp;#x27; with " ' " like

```
if(paramValue.contains("&#x27;")){
                paramValue = paramValue.replace("&#x27;", "'");
}
```

But i know this is not the right way to do it. I want to find the origin of this extra Ampersand. Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: What is the form data?

Comment: Form data as in what are you asking?  It is a URl that is being constructed at the back end.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the ampersand comes from some interference with the browser, and since you tagged your question as *javascript* I think there must be some kind of form, or link, or...

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an apostrophe in some form option or URL, which the browser converts to an entity that is later sent to the web application. Try:

```
<option value="tai%27an City">tai'an City</option>

<a href="www.example.com/foo?bar=tai%27an City">
```

If the data is originally stored as `&#x27;` in the database, it may be the case that it is re-encoded when passed to the user in a web page (i.e. the `&` in `&#x27;` is being re-encoded as `&amp;`). For instance, if you are using JSP, `c:out` escapes such characters unless you specify `<c:out escapeXml="false">`. I couldn't guess more without knowing what steps you are doing, but I hope this can guide you to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes apostrophe is stored to its equivalent ASCII : &#x27; in database..The right value should be tai&amp;#x27;an city and not tai&amp;amp;#x27;an city

Comment: Thanks Javier...I will have a look

Comment: My question should be more clear now...I have highlighted some important things